# Embed file content in ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template, which I use to deploy a resource which has a property that contains a Python script as a string. Instead of having the script in the template file, I would prefer to have it in a .py file, and embed that in the template on deployment.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is using `loadTextContent()` in bicep: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-files#loadtextcontent

If you're not using bicep (and can't) there's no good substitution for it in JSON, you'd have to fashion something to parse the json, figure out where that goes and stringify yourself.

That help?